# GlusterFS Tutorial issue with Typo in command now I can continue

Tags: lamp, high-availability, glusterfs

I currently going through a Udemy.com tutorial on Hight Availability with a LAMP stack.

I have been able to follow along pretty well until it came to setting  up the Volumes for the bricks.

The tutorial said to run this command:

```
sudo gluster volume create var-www replica 2 transport tcp server01-private:/data/glusterfs/var-www/brick01/brick server02-private:/data/glusterfs/var-www/brick02/brick
```

the first time that I ran this command I had a typo in the second half so it failed. I corrected the typo and now when I try to run the command I get this error:

```
volume create: var-www: failed: /data/glusterfs/var-www/brick01/brick or a prefix of it is already part of a volume
```

I have tried to follow the instructions that I found that said to run this:

```
setfattr -x trusted.glusterfs.volumeid $brick_path
```

But this yields something that says

```
The program 'setfattr' is currently not installed. To run 'setfattr' please ask your administrator to install the package 'attr'
```

Anyone with experience in GlusterFS setup can lend a hand in getting this corrected so that I can finish this tutorial?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is done!, in two servers:

sudo apt-get install attr

sudo setfattr -x trusted.gfid /data/glusterfs/var-www/brick01/brick

sudo setfattr -x trusted.glusterfs.volume-id /data/glusterfs/var-www/brick01/brick